# Mule - Get file name from inbound-endpoint

Tags: file, mule

I have a `mule flow` that starts with a `File Component` and it retrieves files from a directory.

How can I get the **filename** instead of the content of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get inbound file name using MEL

```
#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]
```